# Two galleries in the same page[Highslide]

Tags: highslide

i would like to use highslide for a simple gallery whith thumbstrip above.
This is the example from highslide 
http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-thumbstrip-above.html
I would like to add another gallery in the same page,but i don't know how to modify the code..

Here is html of that example only with 2 thumbstrip

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">

<a class='highslide' id="thumb1" href='../images/thumbstrip11.jpg' title="Two cabins"
onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
<img src='../images/thumbstrip11.thumb.png' alt=''/></a>

<div class="hidden-container">
<a class='highslide' href='../images/thumbstrip12.jpg' title="Patterns in the snow"
onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
<img src='../images/thumbstrip12.thumb.png' alt=''/></a>
<a class='highslide' href='../images/thumbstrip14.jpg' title="Old stone cabins"
onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
<img src='../images/thumbstrip14.thumb.png' alt=''/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo page showing how to put more than one gallery in the same page: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/3galleries-thumbstrip-above.html

Study the source code.